# Яндекс цели поставить на клик

Tags: javascript, html, form

Ребят подскажите как на клик по форме поставить яндекс цели

есть код `yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER');`

и форма

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">  
<input type="tel" name="tel-683" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Укажите Ваш телефон">
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-submit"></p>
</form>
```

Нужно скриптом, повесить онсклик на Отправить

Comment: Цель нужна на клик или на отправку формы?

Comment: wpcf7-submit судя по этому классу, это форма с плагина вордпрес.
Чем вам документация официальная не подошла? https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Comment: @Cheg на отправку формы

Comment: @Oleksandr не совсем, там много попап окон - не получилось (

Comment: можно уточнить почему не подошло? https://contactform7.com/dom-events/ на этой странице сразу же пример, как сделать подтверждение для отдельной формы. Вешаете на которую хотите и все... Или в чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, подошел пример